# How to add more parameters to jquery ajax success and error functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In a jquery ajax success/error function like this:

success:

```
function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

}
```

error:

```
function (jqxr, errorCode, errorThrown) {

}
```

Is there a way, I can pass an array of values like this `[A,B,C]` to the ajax function, and then have it come back as

success:

```
function (data, textStatus, jqXHR, A, B, C) {

}
```

error:

```
function (jqxr, errorCode, errorThrown, A, B, C) {

}
```

Thanks

Comment: Why would you want to do that, all you have to do is define that array in a higher scope ?

Comment: I don't want to use inline functions, I want to reference the function defined elsewhere not in scope.

Comment: Then you can use jQuery's `context` option, but that would set the `this-value` not add arguments, or you could use `bind` to do somewhat the same thing, or you could just use the anonymous function and call your other function inside it etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must apply those variables outside the ajax call or you can use "context:" to pass the context which you will have those variables. What you are demonstrating above is not applicable.

UPDATE -

```
var data = ["a", "b"];
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "/s",
        context: data,
        data: data
    }).done(function (result) {
        console.log(this);
    }).error(function (r) {
        console.log(this);
    });
```